# kendo MVC Grid with custom template pop up, which have a grid with inline edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, popupwindow, inline-editing

I have a grid which opens a custom pop-up window

> Editable(ed =>
>   ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("AddEditWorkOrder").Window(w
>   => w.Resizable(r => r.MinWidth(1200).Enabled(true)).Title("Add Work Order"))

In the pop up i have a tab strip and some of the tabs have a grid inside. When I change the edit mode of some of them to

> .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))

the overview grid edit mode is set to inline edit, which is unacceptable. Do you have any clue how to set the inner grid to inline?

Comment: This should not happen, because the  "parent" Grid and "child" Grids are completely unrelated in terms of configuration. Make sure that all Grids have unique Names (IDs) and there is no custom code reused incorrectly.

Comment: I find out it gives me an 'VM3716:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' error in the browser console, when I add **.EditorTemplateName("ToolsDropDownList");** to the column of the inner grid. Something is braking the javascript. Any clue.